# Android Initializing a String[] with getString values?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to make a string array in Android... this works:

```
String titles[] = { "Matches", "Players" };
```

This does not:

```
String titles[] = { getString(R.string.matches), getString(R.string.players) };
```

How can I do what I'm trying to do?

> > java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference

Comment: We'd need a little bit more context. At the point where you're doing this, is there a fully-constructed `Activity` or `Context` instance available?

Comment: please [edit] your post to include more details, like the exact error you see.

Comment: Added the error... it doesnt matter if I put it after the Context or not... still the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably trying to initialize your `String[]` as a class field and that is not allowed because you cannot yet access resources as shown in the exception.

Move the assignment into your `onCreate` method and it will work.

```
private String[] titles;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ....
    titles = new String[] { getString(R.string.matches), getString(R.string.players) };
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
String titles[] = { getResources().getString(R.string.matches), getResources().getString(R.string.players) };
```